# POST Request Firing Twice When Pressing Button After Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, backend

When pressing the button which sends a POST request, the request is fired twice but only after the page is freshly reloaded. The code's function is when the button is pressed, it sends a POST request to the url which then adds 1 to the JSON data value.
This is the button code in script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button">Click Me</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    $("#button").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/updating",
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

This is the nodejs/url code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const PORT = 1000;

// Sets public as static dir
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));

const filepath = "public/data.json"
const rawdata = fs.readFileSync(filepath);

// Addin 1 to JSON value
app.post("/updating", (req, res) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    data.data++;
    var newdata = JSON.stringify({
      data: data.data,
    });
    fs.writeFileSync(filepath, newdata);
  });

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}: http://localhost:${PORT}/`)
);
});
```

JSON file:

```
{"data":29}
```

EDIT: The problem is due to nodemon. This error only occurs when I'm running on dev dependency which only includes nodemon.

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause the event to fire twice. Is it possible to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question?

Comment: `the request is fired twice` Most likely culprit is because you are adding your click handler twice. Replace the click handler `$.ajax` with a `console.log` to verify. Then figure out why/how you are adding your click handler twice to begin with.

Comment: The console.log is only fired once while the request is fired twice. The request will fire once but only once it has fired twice after page reload.